# Alarm clock app, deleting a specific local notification from a UItableView in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, uilocalnotification, alarm

I'm trying to build an alarm clock using UILocalNotification. I am able to schedule alarms and populate them in a UITableView.. Notification alerts are working fine, and I can easily cancel all scheduled notifications. My issues are:

1. How can i delete a specific local notification from the table?
2. How can i keep notifications from disappearing from the table after they have been fired like the apple alarm clock when they black out after being fired.

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

   var notificationArray:NSArray = UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications
   var notification:UILocalNotification = notificationArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as UILocalNotification

   UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)

   alarmTable.reloadData()

      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. From what i understood is while removing the local notification and reloading the table, it would crash because it assumes the row of the deleted notification is still there. So what i did was that i added a command to delete the row under the remove local notification command. And that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a row, use

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([ indexPathRowToDelete ], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
tableViewMain.endUpdates()
```

You do not need to use `reloadData`, since the function will take care of this.

However, if you want to make an entry inactive, e.g. not delete it, use a variable for each data entry which shows whether it is active or not. Check the flag in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. You then can set the flag accordingly and call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`.

Sidenote: accessing `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` to retrieve data is not such a good idea. It is better to pass the data to the data source of your table view.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you explain more, i couldn't implement what you suggested. I tried and got this "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIConcreteLocalNotification row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcf905a00d0'"